# Get overall score in google pagespeed curl request-PHP

Tags: php, google-pagespeed

I am using `v4` google pagespeed API which is till now working fine but suddenlt I get `{{BEGIN_LINK}}`, `{{END_LINK}}` in response, I think that should be removed before we get curl response. To overcome this issue I thought to try `v5`, but it seems `v5` response is complex to understand as compared to `v4`. And my question is how can I get Page Score(0-100) in `v5`?
My code is :

```
$curl_data = curl_request("https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=https://www.ex.com&strategy=desktop", '', 'GET');
$json_data = json_decode($curl_data);
```

In `v4`, I am using `$data = $json_data->formattedResults->ruleResults; $pageScore = $json_data->ruleGroups->SPEED->score;` to get required details. But in `V5` I did not found `formattedResults` or `ruleGroups`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The returned JSON has a section under `lighthouseResult` called categories.

Within `categories` you will see `performance` and then `score` is a child there with the score out of 1 (so a score of 89 would be 0.89).

```
"lighthouseResult": {
......
    "categories": {
        "performance": {
            "id": "performance",
            "title": "Performance",
            "score": 1.00, <- here is the score.
            "auditRefs":
......
```